# What is the scale factor of the two similar triangles?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

Here's the question:
*A triangle has side lengths 7 cm, 10 cm and 15 cm. A similar triangle to it has 25 times the area of the first triangle. Find the length scale factor between the two triangles.*

My answer to this question is $\frac{1}{5}$. I used Heron's formula to solve for the area of the triangle and multiplied it by 25 to get the area of the other triangle. The ratio of their areas is $\frac{1}{25}$. But since the length scale factor is just needed, I just took the square root of $\frac{1}{25}$. But is there any other way to solve this without using any formula for area of triangle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scale factor for areas of similar two-dimensional figures is always $k^2$, where $k$ is the length scale factor. There was no need to compute the actual area of the triangles.